# Python docx code produces emty file - why?

Tags: python, docx

What I am trying to do here is to put descriptions of abilities from one file into another file where the ability names are listed (in the first file there are names and descriptions), but this code produces an empty file. I am very new at coding and learning rn. Help would be very appreciated!

```
import docx

# Open the first Word document
Foci_Desc = docx.Document('C:/Users/User/Documents/Foci_Desc.docx')

# Open the second Word document
Ability_Desc = docx.Document('C:/Users/User/Documents/Ability_Desc.docx')

# Set up a list to store the matched paragraphs
matched_paragraphs = []

# Set up a list to store the matched descriptions
matched_descriptions = []

# Iterate through the paragraphs in the first document
for paragraph in Foci_Desc.paragraphs:
  if 'keyword' in paragraph.text:
    matched_paragraphs.append(paragraph)

# Iterate through the paragraphs in the second document
for paragraph in Ability_Desc.paragraphs:
  if any(p.text == paragraph.text for p in matched_paragraphs):
    matched_descriptions.append(paragraph)

# Create a new Word document
output_document = docx.Document()

# Add the matched paragraphs and descriptions to the new document
for paragraph in matched_paragraphs:
  output_document.add_paragraph(paragraph.text)
for description in matched_descriptions:
  output_document.add_paragraph(description.text)

# Save the new document
output_document.save('C:/Users/User/Documents/output.docx')
```

As I mentioned, I am completely new to coding and I am lost.

Comment: You are only writing to the document if there are `matched_paragraphs` or `match_descriptions`. are you sure those conditions are true?

Comment: It might not be True - if the Paragraph begins with the ability Name, will it write the entire Paragraph into the New document? I basically wanted to make the "search and replace" word function work in Code, but that the Code also finds what to replace with what.